# JButton not displaying on startup but on mouse hover

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, mouseover

I am making 30*30 `JButton` on `JPanel`, but when I launch the app, the buttons does not show up until I hover mouse over them.

I found that this issue is happening mostly with layout set to null, which I don't have and I didn't found any further information about this issue.
I've tried `repaint()` and `validate()`, none of which made difference.

**JPanel:**

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener{

private static final int SIZE_IN_PX = 600; 
private GObject[][] field = new GObject[SIZE_IN_PX / 20][SIZE_IN_PX / 20];
private ArrayList<GObject> minesList = new ArrayList<>();
private GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(SIZE_IN_PX / 20, SIZE_IN_PX / 20);


public Board() {
    setSize(SIZE_IN_PX, SIZE_IN_PX);
    setLayout(layout);
    initBoard();
    initMines();
}


@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
    return;
}

private void initBoard() {
    for (int y = 0; y < SIZE_IN_PX / 20; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE_IN_PX / 20; x++) {
            field[x][y] = new GObject(x, y, false);
            add(field[x][y]);
        }
    }
}

private void initMines() {
    int minesCount = 12;
    for (int i = 0; i < minesCount; i++) {
        int x = (int)(Math.random() * 30);
        int y = (int)(Math.random() * 30);
        field[x][y].setMine(true);
        System.out.println("x:" + x + ", x:" + y);
    }
}
}
```

**JFrame:**

```
public class Window extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Window() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    board1 = new minesweeper.Board();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("MineSweeper");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(board1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 600, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(board1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private minesweeper.Board board1;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

JButton:

```
public class GObject extends JButton{

// vlastnosti
private int y;
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

private boolean mine;
public boolean isMine() {
    return mine;
}
public void setMine(boolean mine) {
    this.mine = mine;
}

private int x;
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

// konstruktor
public GObject(int x, int y, boolean mine) {
    setY(y);
    setMine(mine);
    setX(x);
    setActionListener();
}
```

When I launch the app and put mouse to the center from top left:

[image]

Comment: There isn't a single JButton anywhere in the code you posted. Post the relevant code. Even better, a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: GObject is class that extends JButton, code posted.

Comment: Your GObject class inadvertently overrides getX() and getY() from JComponent. Remove these two methods, and your UI will work as expected. It's generally considered bad practice to extend Swing components like JButton. Use them. And use a data structure like a Map to associate the button with data.

Comment: Thank you, I'll learn to use that.